# How to fix that "Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kdwdteq.mongodb.net"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I will getting that error again and again file running my file app.js

```
Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kdwdteq.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.kdwdteq.mongodb.net'
}
```

Can anyone solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mongodb hostname is correct and you have access to port 27017 from your app.